# Why am I getting this LineUnavailableException?

Tags: java, audio, stream, javasound

I keep getting the LineUnavailableException on line 34 of my code: https://www.refheap.com/21223

The error reads as `javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException: line with format PCM_SIGNED 44100.0 Hz, 16 bit, mono, 2 bytes/frame, little-endian not supported.`.

I'm creating multiple instances of the Sound class (implemented in my refheap paste). It seems that the first instances have no problem. But when I start making new instances of Sound objects using the same audio file then I start getting this error.

Any idea how to fix it?

EIDT: I think the `ByteArrayInputStream` idea from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1854616/in-java-how-can-i-play-the-same-audio-clip-multiple-times-simultaneously) might be what I need to do, but I'm not sure how yet.

EDIT: I thought I found a solution in [this forum thread](http://www.java-gaming.org/index.php?topic=1611.0) on how to play the same sound simultaneously, but after changing my code, I still get the same problem. Here's my updated code, but now the error happens on line 88: https://www.refheap.com/21224

Comment: It seems to be saying it does not know how to handle that particular format of PCM although the format seems fairly standard.

Comment: Yeah, it says that, but it works at first, then when I make too many Sound objects I start having that problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to the problem: [the Beads audio library for Java](http://beadsproject.net). Simply amazing.

Comment: @gpasch I'm not the author of that library, but it certainly made everything easier by giving an API that is intuitive and easy to use compared to native Java.

Answer (score 0):

the exception occurs when you try to open multiple data line at a same time. Second line blocks the opening of first data line.